# Error al añadir libreria mongo-swift-driver XCODE

Tags: mongodb, ios, swift, xcode

Buen dia, tengo un problema estoy realizando una aplicacion prar IOS la cual debe conectarse a una Base de datos de MongoDB, para esto estoy tratando de importar la libreria: mongo-swift-driver
la agrego a mi proyecto pero a la hora de querer compilar me muestra el errror:

"
The package product 'SwiftBSON' requires minimum platform version 13.0 for the iOS platform, but this target supports 9.0
"

Revisando mi proyecto por ningun lado veo de donde toma el valor de 9.0 ya que todo lo tengo orientado a la version 14.5 , adjunto imagenes

llevo dias buscando la solucion y no encuentro nada de como arreglarlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se donde cambiar ese valor de 9.0 a 14.5 si me hace falta cambiarlo en algun lugar?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cómo agregas la librería con pods o package? Si usas package, tienes agregadas las plataformas?

Comment: desde la opcion Swift pakage, ahi pego la url: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-swift-driver............ y descargo, acabo de agregar una imagen de donde lo realizo

Comment: Puedes agregar el código de Package.swift?

Answer (score 2):

Encontre el error y es que la libreria por medio de package no son complatible con IOS, solo es compatible con macOs, la solucion es instalar la misma libreria pero por medio de cocoa pods, basta con seguir el manual de instalacion de cocoapods e instalar la libreria de https://cocoapods.org/pods/MongoSwift